# Writing mixed delimited and not-delimited data to csv file

Tags: python, csv

In this code, some information are written in the csv file. Specifically, I want to ignore any delimited character (comma, space, ...) for the `key` string. In other words, I want to see the key in one Excel cell.  The rest is OK and should be delimited.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.batch.csv')
print(df)

# Creating a dictionary
data = {'Value':[0,0,0]}
kernel_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['M1','M2','M3'])
my_dict = {'dummy':kernel_df}
# dummy  ->          Value
#               M1      0
#               M2      0
#               M3      0

for name, df_group in df.groupby('Name'):
    my_dict[name] = pd.concat(
        [g.reset_index(drop=True) for _, g in df_group.groupby('ID')['Value']],
        axis=1
    )

print(my_dict)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key in my_dict.keys():
        f.write("%s\n"%(key))   <-- This should be written in one cell
        df2 = my_dict[key]
        df2.to_csv(f)
```

The output is

```
   ID                  Name Metric  Value
0   0  K1::foo(bar::z(x,u))     M1     10
1   0  K1::foo(bar::z(x,u))     M2      5
2   0  K1::foo(bar::z(x,u))     M3     10
3   1             K2::foo()     M1     20
4   1             K2::foo()     M2     10
5   1             K2::foo()     M3     15
6   2  K1::foo(bar::z(x,u))     M1      2
7   2  K1::foo(bar::z(x,u))     M2      2
8   2  K1::foo(bar::z(x,u))     M3      2
{'dummy':     Value
M1      0
M2      0
M3      0, 'K1::foo(bar::z(x,u))':    Value  Value
0     10      2
1      5      2
2     10      2, 'K2::foo()':    Value
0     20
1     10
2     15}
```

And the CSV file in Excel looks like

[image]

[image]

As you can see the 6th row is split into two columns. The output file in plain text looks like

```
dummy
,Value
M1,0
M2,0
M3,0
K1::foo(bar::z(x,u))
,Value,Value
0,10,2
1,5,2
2,10,2
K2::foo()
,Value
0,20
1,10
2,15
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Could you please give an example of what `my_dict` looks like? And an example of what you want the `csv` output to look like?

Comment: @SamBob: Please see the updated post.

Comment: The way the file is in Excel depends on the file itself and of Excel config. Excel is known to have a poor support of csv files. Could you 1/ show the file **as text** and 2/ tell us what are your locale parameters so that you can try to guess your Excel config.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Please see the updated post. I have to say that this is LibreOffice Calc but I expect similar thing in Microsoft Excel too.

Comment: @mahmood: Sorry. But you currently write the key on on row and not formatted as a csv cell should be, and then the values on next rows. I understand that it is not what you want, but do you really want the key to be on its own row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the csv module to ensure that special characters in the key will be correctly quoted or escaped. As you use the default formattings, ie a comma delimiter and a double quote as string delimiter, you can use the defaults for the csv module. Your code would become:

```
import csv
...
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    for key in my_dict.keys():
        wr.writerow([key])  # ensure proper CSV formatting of the key cell
        df2 = my_dict[key]
        df2.to_csv(f)
```

With you sample data the content of the csv file is:

```
dummy
,Value
M1,0
M2,0
M3,0
"K1::foo(bar::z(x,u))"
,Value,Value
0,10,2
1,5,2
2,10,2
K2::foo()
,Value
0,20
1,10
2,15
```

You can see the the csv writer has correctly quoted the second key because it contains a comma...